# Show a Camera Activity which runs tflite on image frames in a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera, tensorflow-lite, flutter-platform-channel

I have an android app having a **CameraActivity** which runs a **tflite classifier** periodically on image frames from the preview stream. The implementation of the Camera and tflite works great in the Android part and gives a good FPS.

I want to show this **CameraActivity** in my Flutter App as a Screen. The Flutter app has all the Frontend and UI part implemented already.

I've already tried using the official Flutter [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin to implement the same by using **camera.startImageStream** but was unable to get matching FPS and the Camera Preview lags when calling the tflite model asynchronously using **methodChannel**.

I also came across [AndroidView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AndroidView-class.html) which embeds an Android view in the Widget hierarchy but the docs say it is an expensive operation and should be avoided when a Flutter equivalent is possible.

Is there a way to write a plugin for showing the **CameraActivity** (i.e. the UI) on the Flutter end similar to the way methodChannel is used for exchanging data between the Flutter and the Native codes. Or if there's another possible way of achieving this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Flutter side
Future<Null> showNativeView() async {

  
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {//check if platform is android
    var methodChannel = MethodChannel("methodchannelname");//create a method channel name 
    await methodChannel.invokeMethod('showNativeCameraView');//create method name
  }
}

Container(
child: InkWell(
onTap: () {
showNativeView();//call to open native android activity
},
child: Center(
child: new Text("takeimage"))))

//Android side 


//inside mainactivity on create
var channel: MethodChannel? = null


channel = MethodChannel(flutterView, "methodchannelname");
MethodChannel(flutterView, "methodchannelname")//same as flutterside 
    .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
if (call.method == "showNativeCameraView") {//same methodname as flutterside
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityCamera::class.java)//native camera activity code can be added in the android folder of the flutter application
startActivity(intent)
result.success(true)
} else {
result.notImplemented()
}

}
```

This link will help u further
https://medium.com/@Chetan/flutter-communicate-with-android-activity-or-ios-viewcontroller-through-method-channel-c11704429cd0